# Factorization of really big numbers in C

Tags: c, math, numbers, integer, primes

I am writing an article regarding the importance of the Prime numbers on today's criptography. I want to develop a small application showing how long a program written in C (low level language, at least to me) would take to factorize a compound number in its prime factors. I came up with a simple algorithm to do so, but I ran into a problem:

I would like the user to be able to type gigantic numbers, for example: 7777777777777777777777777772

So the computer would take some hours to process that, showing how good our criptography based upon primes is.

But in C the largest data type I could find was *LONG* which goes up to 2147483646.

Do you guys know how I could be able to type and process a big number in C?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for "multiple word integers" or "arbitrary precision integers". There are libraries such as GMP to do arithmetic on such objects.

Comment: "in C the largest data type I could find was LONG" --> Try `uintmax_t`.  That is at least `18446744073709551615`.  Not quite enough for 7777777777777777777777777772, a 93 bit number.  Look to implementations  that support `int128_t`.  Of course that number `777...772` is not a prime.

Comment: But even if you do this, it would just show how your algorithm behaves, and not so much that factorization is actually hard.

Comment: @harold, how do you think would be the best way to show to students how hard it is for a modern computer to factorize a compound number in its prime factors? I am opened to suggestions because I do want them to understand this concept

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. Factorization techniques for larger numbers, such as GNFS, take a lot of ground work to understand what they do, and are too complicated to reproduce as an exercise. The simpler algorithms have a lot of trouble with numbers that are, these days, not considered hard to factor, such as RSA-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Factorization of really big numbers
>   I would like the user to be able to type gigantic numbers, for example: 7777777777777777777777777772

That is a 93 bit number, not that gigantic, so one could simplistically brute force it.

---

Something like the below if you have access to a `unsigned __int128`.  C does specify 64-bit types, yet beyond that, you are on your own.

This modest factorization I'd estimate could take some minutes.

https://www.dcode.fr/prime-factors-decomposition reports the answer in seconds.

Of course **many** improvement can be had.

```
unsigned __int128 factor(unsigned __int128 x) {
  if (x <= 3) {
    return x;
  }
  if (x %2 == 0) return 2;
  for (unsigned __int128 i = 3; i <= x/i; i += 2) {
    static unsigned long n = 0;
    if (++n >= 100000000) {
      n = 0;
      printf(" %llu approx %.0f\n", (unsigned long long) i, (double)(x/i));
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    if (x%i == 0) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return x;
}

void factors(unsigned __int128 x) {
  do {
    unsigned __int128 f = factor(x);
    printf("%llu approx %.0f\n", (unsigned long long) f, (double)x);
    fflush(stdout);
    x /= f;
  } while (x > 1);
}

void factors(unsigned __int128 x) {
  do {
    unsigned __int128 f = factor(x);
    printf("approx %0.f approx %.0f\n", (double) f, (double)x);
    fflush(stdout);
    x /= f;
  } while (x > 1);
}
```

Output

```
approx 2 approx 7777777777777778308713283584
approx 2 approx 3888888888888889154356641792
approx 487 approx 1944444444444444577178320896
approx 2687 approx 3992699064567647864619008
 99996829 approx 14859790387308
 199996829 approx 7429777390798
 299996829 approx 4953158749339
 399996829 approx 3714859245385
 499996829 approx 2971882684351
 ...
 38399996829 approx 38696146902
 38499996829 approx 38595637421
approx 1485931918335559335936 approx 1485931918335559335936
```

---

The right answer though is to use more efficient algorithms and *then* consider the types needed.

Comment: Thanks, man! It opened my mind to the issue! I guess it is the right way to go! As I said, as soon as I finish this project which is for educational purposes, I post here the Github repository! Cheers from Brazil

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do it on paper. You break the number into pieces and use long division, long addition, and long multiplication.

Perhaps the simplest way is to store the number as a base 10 string and write code to do all the operations you need on those strings. You would do addition with carries the same way you do it on paper. Multiplication would be done with single-digit multiplication combined with addition (which you'd have already don). And so on.

There are plenty of libraries available to do this for you such as libgmp's MPZ library and OpenSSL's BN library.

Comment: in order to break the numbers into pieces I would have to break it on a char array, right? Turns out it is too difficult to do in C, it would be much easier to do using Java, for instance. Would you recommend me to use Java or is there another alternative in C?

Comment: @MatheusMinguini I would use gmp in C, or BigInteger in Java. I prefer C myself, but that's entirely a personal preference for the language itself.

Comment: @MatheusMinguini Choice of language is a personal preference, but I wouldn't recommend C because the lack of classes with destructors and value semantics makes it hard to use. C++ with, for example, boost multiprecision would be a fine choice. JavaScript has a nice big number library available too.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered and helped me with this issue! I am truly grateful! I ended up using Java, as soon as I finish the project, I post here the GitHub repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use a struct, and just set the numbers you want, the code below is not tested but should give you some direction.

I believe this should give you the ability to get somewhere around 4294967295 (max_int) to the power of x x being the places you define in the struct

```
typedef struct big_number{
    int thousands;
    int millions;
    int billions;
}

//Then do some math
big_number add(big_number n1, big_number n2){
    int thousands = n1.thousands + n2.thousands; 
    int millions = n1.millions + n2.millions;
    //etc... (note each part of your struct will have a maximum value of 999
    if(thousands > 999){
         int r = thousands - 999;
         millions += r; //move the remainder up
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I did test it and it worked!  But I preferred to use Java which is a language that I am more used to and with more experience! I did appreciate your effort on helping me out though! Thanks again

Comment: I didn't know you where asking for java, but I do assume ( not knowing java ) you could do something of the same sorts, You're welcome!